# Api "401 - Unauthenticated" error after update laravel version

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel launchs a [security release](https://blog.laravel.com/security-release-laravel-61827-7220). I'm using Laravel 6.18.12 and trying to update to 6.18.29, so when I updated my composer.json file with `"laravel/framework": "^6.18.29"` I take this error:

[image]

Reading about it in stackoverflow I see that people that installed the doctrine/inflector at 1.4 fixed their problems. So I did it: `composer install doctrine/inflector:1.4` and try update again the laravel with `composer update laravel/framework` but a new error happened:

[image]

Them I installed also the symfony/polyfill-php7.3 (I'm using PHP 7.3). Done that I could update the Laravel version, but I'm always getting this error  401 once I try to get my api data:

[image]

This happens to all my api requests. Looks like something about the auth:api middleware, but I'm not sure why. My user is logged in the web, I can use auth() stuff, but the api looks like the user isn't authenticated. Everything was working as fine before this update.

Ps: I'm not using passport, but I'm using spark alongside my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, this Laravel patch has to been solved also in the Spark, so now I'm updating to the newest version. For further information: [Taylor answer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/33698#event-3600558926)